# how to get the un answered questions in quetion table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql5

I have a two tables

```
question
------------------------------
qid  |  qname  |  description
------------------------------
1      ssc?       blabla

2      BIE        blabla

3      msc        blabla

answer
----------------------------
aid  | uid  | qid | answered_on
-------------------------------
1      1      1     ssc means

2      2      1     ssc
-------------------------------
```

Now i want to get the un answered questions how to write the query?can You tell any one.

```
i get the result like 

qid | qname
-----------
2     BIE
3     msc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from  users as ru left join answers as ra on ru.uid=ra.uid 
left join questions as rq on rq.uid=ru.uid 
where   rq.qid not in(select qid from answers) group by rq.qid order by rq.qid desc
```

this is may be usefull check it if you have a users table

Comment: Lol, well this whole thing sounds very strange...
"Here is a random table that maybe you have" "Yes I do have it, it is working properly"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT qid, qname FROM question 
WHERE qid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT qid FROM answer)
```

Not really a server fault question though.